# parsing first character of e164 string separately in python

Tags: python, string, parsing, phone-number

```
def parse_num(raw_phone):
    parsed = ''.join([c for c in raw_phone if c.isdigit() or c == '+'])
    return parsed
```

I am looking to clean a string prior to passing it to [python-phonenumbers](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers) for final validation as non-numerical characters cause failure.

I have amended the string above to remove anything non-numerical or '+' to work with international numbers. But, if a plus appears later in the string it will also not be removed causing failure.
I have an idea of how to do this 'the long way' but I am wondering if anyone can suggest a cleaner method.

I am looking for something along the lines of:

```
[c for c in raw_phone if c.isdigit() or first character == '+']
```

Any help or some pointing in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with removing all the non-digit characters except the starting `+` symbol?

```
re.sub(r'(?!^\+)\D', r'', phonenum)
```

`(?!^\+)\D` forces the regex engine to match any non-digit characters but not of 
[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cR7xK2/3)

*Example:*

```
>>> def parsenum(raw_phone):
        return re.sub(r'(?!^\+)\D', r'', raw_phone)

>>> parsenum('+foo456753bar+452')
'+456753452'
```

OR

```
>>> def parsenum(raw_phone):
        res = ""
        if raw_phone[0] == '+':
            res = res + '+'
        for c in raw_phone:
            if c.isdigit():
                res = res + c
        return res

>>> parsenum('+foo456753bar+452')
'+456753452'
```

Comment: That is exactly what i was looking for!
I had come upon similar to your second result but wanted to keep it as concise as possible, your first option is ideal, thank you!